# Jeux Sans Frontières related question

Tags: sens, orthographe

First, don't wonder, the only French sentence I can speak is probably [Legammanexistepa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Gammas!_Les_Gammas!), and I would even have to look up the spelling. Still, I have an excellent *phonetic* memory, and the title of the song I'm after, and which played an age ago as an act during "Jeux Sans Frontières" is "Ils sont là bas" (so much I found out myself, . The refrain, phonetically, is "Lüüsi copy lää", which more sounds like Finnish, and I was not able to turn that into meaningful French. Googling or Youtube brought nothing up either. Anyone who can help me to the lyrics of the song or at least have an idea what my "Finnish" really means?

EDIT: Using the phonetic table, "Lysi kɔpi lɛː".

Comment: It would be helpful to use the [IPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet) to explain what you remember hearing. [French phonems](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aide:Alphabet_phon%C3%A9tique_fran%C3%A7ais)

Comment: Puzzling. Do you remember the year it happened? How did the singer(s) look like?

Comment: Hmm... Is it `ɔ` or could it be `ɔ̃` ? Is it `ly` or could it be `lɥi`? Above all, is it possible it's something like: « [avec] lui, c'est compliqué » ?

Comment: @Luke *Lucie, copie les !*

Comment: @jlliagre: First I thought "Eh, what?", but now that I think of it, the chorus (it was a large group singing, think Les Humphries) might point to the others "là bas" and tells Lucie to follow their example...maybe that solves the riddle. I googled the pronounciation of the name, it fits.

Comment: @Hauke Any timeframe? Jeux sans frontières lasted a long time... How old were you, back then?

Comment: @DerniersOutrages: I surely was a kid, which means 50 years ago is correct +-5 years. Jokers could be played to increase score, if that info nails it down too.

Comment: @Hauke I see. I have a friend who works @ l'INA (French National TV archives). I'll ask him to give it a look, and keep you posted. It's a shot in the dark, really.